# EEPROM read and write for 5 bits

Tags: c, avr, eeprom

I have this code that write and write from **EEPROM** for 4 digit number. 
`For Ex: 2356`

Code;

```
void WritePassToEEPROM(uint16_t pass)
{
   EEPROMWrite(0000,(pass%100));
   EEPROMWrite(0001,(pass/100));
}

uint16_t ReadPassFromEEPROM()
{
   return (EEPROMRead(0001)*100  +  EEPROMRead(0000));
}
```

The `Write_Pass_To_EEPROM()` function writes to 2 addresses `0000` and `0001`. for `2356`, `2356%100` is `56` and `2356/100` is `23`. So, at address `0000` it will be 56 and at address `0001` it will be `23`.
While reading `EEPROM_Read(0000)` will return `34` and `EEPROM_Read(0001)*100` will return `2300`. `2300 + 56` is `2356`.

But if i need to write `5` digit number like `65238` what should i do.

Comment: Why would you waste 61% of each byte like that?

Comment: Why use *decimal* arithmetic? You do know that 16 bits (two bytes) as an unsigned integer can contain values between `0` and `65535` (inclusive).

Comment: If he wants to store things such as `99999` (for which 16 bits are too little and 32 are too much), then go 24-bit or something... Or maybe he has to deal with some old crufty hardware/software that works with BCD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will go up to 0xffff (65535).

```
void WritePassToEEPROM(uint16_t pass)
{
   EEPROMWrite(0000,(pass & 0x00ff));
   EEPROMWrite(0001,(pass & 0xff00) >> 8);
}

uint16_t ReadPassFromEEPROM()
{
   return ((uint16_t)(EEPROMRead(0001) << 8)  +  (uint16_t)EEPROMRead(0000));
}
```